# how to adapt an url in sqlite database to imageview

Tags: android, sqlite, picasso, android-glide

I have a list of image urls in my sqlite database(prepoulated) stored in "pictures" column, and i want to adapt them to my imageview in child_list using a glide or picasso library. 
i'm using a simpletreecursoradapater for an expendablelistview and that's what complicate adapting answers in other questions.
i'm new to android. so please show me where to add the suggested code..thanks

this is my Database.java

```
public class Database {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "URTd.db";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "OrganAnatomy";
    public static final String DATABASE_ID = "_id";
    public static final String DATABASE_GROUP_1 = "Larynx_features";
    public static final String DATABASE_CHILD_1 = "Larynx";
    public static final String DATABASE_CHILD_2 = "pictures";


    public void open() {
        mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mContext, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        mDB = mDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public Cursor getDatabase() {
        String whereclause = DATABASE_CHILD_1 + " IS NOT NULL";
        return mDB.query(DATABASE_TABLE, null, whereclause, null, null, null, DATABASE_ID);
    }
```

and this is my Main.activity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ExpandableListView expandableListView;
    Database mDatabase;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDatabase = new Database(this);
        mDatabase.open();


        Cursor cursor = mDatabase.getDatabase();
        startManagingCursor(cursor);


        String[] childFrom = new String[]{Database.DATABASE_CHILD_1,Database.DATABASE_CHILD_2};
        String[] groupFrom = new String[]{Database.DATABASE_GROUP_1};

        int[] groupTo = {R.id.group1};
        int[] childTo = {R.id.child1,R.id.child2};

        SimpleCursorTreeAdapter simplecursortreeAdapter = new ExpandableListViewAdapter(
                this,
                cursor,
                R.layout.list_group,
                groupFrom,
                groupTo,
                R.layout.list_child,
                childFrom,
                childTo
        );

        expandableListView = findViewById(R.id.expandableListview);
        expandableListView.setAdapter(simplecursortreeAdapter);

    }

    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mDatabase.close();
    }

    private class ExpandableListViewAdapter extends SimpleCursorTreeAdapter {
        private ExpandableListViewAdapter(
                Context context,
                Cursor cursor,
                int groupLayout,
                String[] groupFrom,
                int[] groupTo,
                int childLayout,
                String[] childFrom,
                int[] childTo) {
            super(context, cursor, groupLayout, groupFrom, groupTo, childLayout, childFrom, childTo);
        }


        protected Cursor getChildrenCursor(Cursor groupCursor) {
            return mDatabase.getID(groupCursor.getInt(groupCursor.getColumnIndex(Database.DATABASE_ID)));
```

Main.activity.xml

```
<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/expandableListview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

child_list.xml

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/child1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/child2"
    />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lets make a simple class contain two Strings and name it FirstClass

```
public class FirstClass {
String text;
String Image;

public FirstClass(String text, String image) {
    this.text = text;
    Image = image;
}

public String getText() {

    return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}

public String getImage() {
    return Image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    Image = image;
}
}
```

after that you have to query your database and return a cursor  after that call it on your main Activity use this loop to convert your cursor to List

```
ArrayList<FirstClass> mArrayList = new ArrayList<FirstClass>();
for(mCursor.moveToFirst(); !mCursor.isAfterLast(); mCursor.moveToNext()) {
mArrayList.add(mCursor.getString(Text_COLUMN_INDEX),
mCursor.getString(Image_COLUMN_INDEX));
}
```

now you can have list for both of your text and Image URL now it's time to add this data to our adapter we will name it FirstAdapter

```
FirstAdapter adapter = new FirstAdapter (getActivity(),mArrayList );
```

and  set the adapter to your list, for your adapter it will be like that

```
public class FirstAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<FirstClass> {


/**
 * Create a new {@link FirstAdapter} object.
 *
 * @param context    is the current context (i.e. Activity) that the adapter is being created in.
 * @param firstClass is the list of {@link firstClass}s to be displayed.
 */
public WordAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<FirstClass> firstClass) {
    super(context, 0, firstClass);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    View listItemView = convertView;
    if (listItemView == null) {
        listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.child_list, parent, false);
    }

    // Get the {@link Word} object located at this position in the list
    FirstClass currentWord = getItem(position);

    // Find the TextView in the child_list.xml layout
    TextView textView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.child1);

    textView.setText(currentWord.getText());

    // Find the ImageView in the child_list.xml layout with the ID image.
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.child2);
    try {
        Picasso.with(context).load(currentWord.getImage()).into(holder.imageView);
        Log.e("Images", " PIC  " + image);
    } catch (Exception o) {
        Log.e("Images", "NOOOOOOOOO PIC  " + position);
    }


    // Return the whole list item layout  so that it can be shown in
    // the ListView.
    return listItemView;
}
}
```

feel free to accept the answer and if I didn't help you try to search in the Internet you will find many examples

Comment: sound like a good answer to another query ..after making a resaerch on interent i discovered that i need to add viewbinder ..are you familiar with that?

Answer (score 0):

inside your adapter make a method named setData() that accept array of Strings (all Images urls you want to display in your expandableListView ) and call this method when you want to set the Images to your adapter which will look like that

```
void setData(List<String> imagesUrls){
listItems.addAll(imagesUrls);
notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

where listItems is a local variable inside your adapter and when you want to set each Image to certain position you can just do this

```
    String image;

        image = listItems.get(position);


    try {
        Picasso.with(context).load(image).into(holder.imageView);
        Log.e("Images", " PIC  " + image);
    } catch (Exception o) {
        Log.e("Images", "NOOOOOOOOO PIC  " + position);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ..and I'm sorry for those stupid questions: 1/i think your solution imply that i won't use sqlite database to retrieve urls, and i'll just create a string of URLs? (which is fantastic if true,) 2/i did add voidsetData under     private class ExpandableListViewAdapter extends SimpleCursorTreeAdapter (please see above to see if it's the right place) but i keep getting ListItems highlighted red! 3/ for the second part you mentioned i should add, where exactly and what are the thing to modify in it! ...thanks a lot and sorry for bothering you

Comment: i'm using a SimpleCursorTreeAdapter, do you think your solution will work?

Comment: @MikeT this is my second question, if you have time , thanks again

Comment: If you use sqlite database or string of URLs you can use the same code but the problem is in your SimpleCursorTreeAdapter it will not help and my solution is only applied to custom adapters if you want I can provide you with a simple code to explain the whole process in case that you will use a costum adapter

Comment: Chokran Sahb! ..yeah i would love to, just to explain my goal..i'm creating expendable list with info being extratced from a prepopulated database ..if you could make a custom adapter for that ..that would be great! for my database.java ..you'll find it above